Re-initialize cpp std::mutex in child process
I have std::mutex in parent process. Parent process forks a child process. Child process blocks on acquiring the lock. It might be due to parent process has acquire the lock.
I have read that child process gets copy of parent mutexes with their current states. Also, unlocking the mutex in a thread which does not own it causes undefined behaviour.
How should I reinitailize or unlock the std::mutex in child process, so that it does not blocked?

Is fork done while the mutex is locked in the parent ? Is so - can you avoid it ? In general std::mutex is not meant for inter-process.

Actually my code is in a library which gets loaded inside application using ld_preload, so fork is done in the application while mutex is in my library

you dont have to "reinitialize", if you really want the forked process to use a different mutex you could just use a different one

The mutex needs to be in shared memory, so it is shared between processes. The act of allocating the mutex needs to be changed - there is nothing the child process can do.

fork() forks only one thread. If the mutex is locked by another thread, you get it locked forever.

This question is similar to: Possible Thread Starvation in C++. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If your code is in the library, either don't preload it in the forking applications (document the behavior for collaborators), or don't use std::mutex. Best is to refactor your design; maybe try boost.interprocess or other libraries instead of fork. Idiomatic way is to use fork ASAP, followed by spawn. But imstead, it's often abused to run complex colabrative logic in child and parrent. That approach hits the hard wall when using C++.

Documentation of fork clearly states what happens with std::mutex (it just reefers explicitly to C-API):
fork(2) - Linux manual page

Note the following further points:

The child process is created with a single thread—the one that called fork(). The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.


So when your application uses multiple threads. Then one of threads is holding a lock on std::mutex and during that time, fork is called:

child process will have only one thread running - clone of thread which invoked fork
mutexes locked by other threads of parent process will remain lock forever in a child process (you can't resume threads which were running with parent process).

In theory you can try add those callbacks with pthread_atfork to enforce proper state of mutexes, but this looks quite complex. Only details of your problem can give a hint how to address this issue.

You need to understand what fork does. When you fork(), you get a second process -- almost as if you run your program twice. Except the second process is a complete copy of the original. It doesn't share memory -- it's a copy. The only difference between them is the actual return value from fork() itself -- the parent gets the PID of the child, and the child gets 0. Otherwise at the conclusion of fork(), both processes have identical memory.
At this point, you have two mutexes -- one in each process. They aren't linked in any way, as they are now separate. (Unless you're using some sort of cross-process mutex, which you didn't mention.)
If the mutex was locked at the start of the fork() it's still locked -- in each process. And freeing the lock in the parent process does nothing in the child process.
So your child process is probably going to block forever, although I haven't tested that myself.
Your child should do some special processing. Specifically, you might have to unlock that mutex manually.

Note that Red Wave points out issues with thread IDs and relationships to mutex locks. This is clearly a bit of a mess, and these types of issues are why old school programmers typically follow one of two patterns.

Use threads if you're going to continue your current work
Fork and exec if you really need a separate process

You'll need to do some testing.

fork cannot copy thread ids, because theyare system-wide unique. Therefore any behavior depending on thread ids will result in UB. That's why locked mutexes always create problems - even if locked by main thread. Because lock usually depends on thread id and main thread too, has an id. If the mutex state -in a specific implementation-  does not depend on thread id, it will not cause problems; but that's not the general case. Thus, I am afraid this reply might not provide a reliable solution to the original problem.


How should I reinitailize or unlock the std::mutex in child process, so that it does not blocked?

I think that the key issue might be about a mutex was locked in the parent process at the time of forking, and then it will appear as locked in the child as well.
Maybe try to use POSIX pthread_atfork with pthread_mutex instead of fork (refer to Linux/UNIX system: pthread_atfork). The mechanism allows to register handlers to prepare and restore mutexes during a fork().

The intent of
pthread_atfork() was to provide a mechanism whereby the
application (or a library) could ensure that mutexes and other
process and thread state would be restored to a consistent state.
In practice, this task is generally too difficult to be
practicable.

Here’s a simple example:
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void prepare() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
}

void parent() {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void child() {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main() {
    pthread_atfork(prepare, parent, child);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        // Child process
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        std::cout << "Child acquired the lock" << std::endl;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        std::cout << "Child released the lock" << std::endl;
    } else {
        // Parent process
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        std::cout << "Parent acquired the lock" << std::endl;
        // execute some tasks
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        std::cout << "Parent released the lock" << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Hope this is helpful in resolving this issue.
